# How can I extract the data from a felt map into a csv file?

Tags: javascript, excel, database

I need to extract all the data from the following map but I don't see how I can do it. Thank you!!!

https://felt.com/map/HPE-Windmill-34Nr1KNFSEmf55Pgx89AP3D?lat=40.122624&lon=-3.100995&zoom=6.747214399095749

I have tried to get the data with the excel function to get data, but it has not worked

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - search SO for answers.  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Terms of use: "Prohibited Uses. You may use the Service only for lawful purposes and in accordance with this Agreement. You agree not to use the Service: Use any robot, spider, or other automatic device, process, or means to access the Service for any purpose, including monitoring or copying any of the material on the Service."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ".geojson" at the end of the link:

https://felt.com/map/HPE-Windmill-34Nr1KNFSEmf55Pgx89AP3D.geojson